# How to divide too long header-arguments of src-block into multiple lines?

Tags: org-mode, org-table, literate-programming, header-line

I'm trying to process tens of tables (from multiple org-files) in python src-block at once.

Suppose that the following file: `/tmp/file1.org` contains some tables:

```org
* This org contains the tables
#+name: table_example_1
| 1 | 2 | 3 |
| 4 | 5 | 5 |

#+name: table_example_2
| a | b | c |
| d | e | f |

#+name: table_example_3
| a1 | b2 | c3 |
| d4 | e5 | f6 |
```

AFAIK (to use all tables from previous org-file), I have the following two methods:

```org
* method 1
#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output :var tbl1=/tmp/file1.org:table_example_1 tbl2=/tmp/file1.org:table_example_2 tbl3=/tmp/file1.org:table_example_3
print(tbl1)
print(tbl2)
print(tbl3)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 5]]
: [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
: [['a1', 'b2', 'c3'], ['d4', 'e5', 'f6']]

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
* method 2
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args: :var tbl1=/tmp/file1.org:table_example_1 tbl2=/tmp/file1.org:table_example_2 tbl3=/tmp/file1.org:table_example_3
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output 
print(">", tbl1)
print(">", tbl2)
print(">", tbl3)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: > [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 5]]
: > [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
: > [['a1', 'b2', 'c3'], ['d4', 'e5', 'f6']]
```

**Problem:** You can see that lines `#+BEGIN_SRC python ....`  and `:header-args: ...` are very long. Now imagine, there are 20-30 tables. It's quite annoying to manage this long line.

---

**Question:**

- Is it possible to divide these too long `header-arguments` into multiple lines to make it easy to manage?
- Or is there an easier method to achieve what I'm doing?

Comment: you could also export your tables to csv with `org-table-export` and read the csv from Python.

Comment: That's a good idea, definitely will try it

Comment: It shouldn't be too complicated to build a function to automatically export all the tables in your org file to csv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found out the existence of `:header-args+:`. (from another [question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/57833/confusion-about-header-arguments?rq=1)).

So following works:

```
* method 3
:PROPERTIES:
:header-args:  :var table1=/tmp/file1.org:table_example_1 
:header-args+: :var table2=/tmp/file1.org:table_example_2 
:header-args+: :var table3=/tmp/file1.org:table_example_3
:END:

#+BEGIN_SRC python :results output 
print("<", table1)
print("<", table2)
print("<", table3)
#+END_SRC

#+RESULTS:
: < [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 5]]
: < [['a', 'b', 'c'], ['d', 'e', 'f']]
: < [['a1', 'b2', 'c3'], ['d4', 'e5', 'f6']
```